# Selecting all records plus earliest date from many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I've got two tables in a mysql database of hikes and peaks:

```
hikes: HikeID, Date, Name, Route, ...
peaks: PeakID, Name, Altitude, ...
```

Both are linked in a many-to-many relationship by a table called 'hp_links'. What I want to get is a list of all peaks, and against each one the earliest date it was climbed.

I came up with the following:

```
SELECT peaks.PeakID, peaks.Name, MIN(hikes.Date) AS FirstClimbed
FROM peaks
INNER JOIN hp_links ON peaks.PeakID = hp_links.PeakID
INNER JOIN hikes ON hp_links.HikeID = hikes.HikeID
GROUP BY peaks.PeakID
```

It does work, however it doesn't include peaks which don't have any entries in the link table (ie. haven't been climbed). I changed the first INNER JOIN (to 'hp_links') to a LEFT JOIN, but this didn't seem to make any difference. I then changed the second INNER JOIN (to 'hikes') to a RIGHT JOIN. This made a difference in that I got an additional record which consisted of peaks.PeakID = NULL, peaks.Name = NULL, and FirstClimbed = the date of a hike which had no peaks linked anyway.

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both joins should be left joins. Otherwise the second inner join will not include peaks with no hp_links.

Comment: Thanks, I think I tried every combo of left/right/inner/outer joins except both 'LEFT'. Works now!